# How to perform action on custom nuget install/uninstall?

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package, editorconfig

I have built a nuget which installs .editorconfig file in project on build and it works fine with the following in the props file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EditorConfigFilesToCopy Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../content/.editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyEditorConfig" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Copying files from '@(EditorConfigFilesToCopy)' to '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)'" />
    <Copy
      SourceFiles="@(EditorConfigFilesToCopy)"
      DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
      UseHardlinksIfPossible="false" />
  </Target>
```

Now I would like to remove that file on nuget uninstall, and to install it too on nuget install.
Is there any way to do that? I can't find any replacement for (un)install.ps1 scripts which are deprecated.

Thanks